# Issue with selecting the range probably because the last column and last row is set incorrectly

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select the range and for all colour cells, paste 0.

I do not understand why this code not working. I went through a couple of options from the forum but still does not work. I am pretty sure this is something to do with the last row and last column and it is something obvious.

Could you please advise what I am doing wrong here?

```
Dim cell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim LRRow As Long, LRCol As Long

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

         LRRow = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
         LRCol = .Cells(.Rows.Count, LRRow).End(xlUp).row

        Set rng = .Range(Cells(7, 4), Cells(LRRow, LRCol))


       ' Selection.AutoFilter
       ' Range("A1").Select


        For Each cell In rng

            If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 204) And cell.Value = "" Then
             cell.Value = 0
            End If

        Next cell

        End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

```
 LRRow = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 LRCol = .Cells(.Rows.Count, LRRow).End(xlUp).row
```

TO

```
LRRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, LRRow).End(xlUp).row
LRCol = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :D Much appreciated!